# Size of the screens in float

Tags: android, graphics, floating-point

Because the graphics functions (such as "drawLine") require you to type parameters in "float" and not in "int"?

Perhaps because the size of the various Android devices vary in "int" as they are always the same in "float"?

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, drawing is done through a GPU that does all its calculations using floating point types.  This is also what allows things like [subpixel rendering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering) to work.  Also, you are free to do a series of complex computations using floats without having to worry about whether or not it's better to round up or down for the current display type. Android will handle that for you with the float you provide.

It is true that Android is not consistent in asking for float or int, but when the measurement is for raw pixels, they are still measuring the exact same thing, so the measurement for floating point pixels of 5.0 is the same as int 5.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I DO NOT UNDERSTAND one thing:
the size of the various screens of the various Android devices vary in "int" but they are always THE SAME in "float"? Yes or No?